# How to insert two <input> types in a one line?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

```
input type = "radio" name = "trvltype" value = "oneway" id = "oneway" onclick = optionbuton()>One Way
<span style = "display:inline-block;width:65px">
</span>
<input type = "radio" name = "trvltype" value = "return" id = "return" onclick = optionbuton()>Return
```

This is a part of my code.I want to add two option buttons in a one line.I used  tag with style attribute.I have to insert more radio buttons(more than two in a one line.) after this.so each time i have to insert `<span>`.but all radio buttons isn't come Straight.Is there any way to fix this in Dreamweaver?

Comment: Please provide HTML context... Also, why you need span tag? Radio buttons will be placed inline, by default: http://jsfiddle.net/1b0f0Lex/

Comment: yep but how to get them straight.I use span for get them straight line.but it was too hard?.@nevermind

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by not giving any 
 tags !
Just by Typing
   `First Name<input type="text" name="fname" />`
`Last name<input type="text" name"lname" />`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Radio Button</title></head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li  style="list-style:none;">
     <input type = "radio" name = "trvltype" value = "oneway" id = "oneway" onclick = optionbuton()>One Way
  <input type = "radio" name = "trvltype" value = "return" id = "return" onclick = optionbuton()>Return
    </li>
</ul>

</body
</html>
```

According to your question hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Radio Button</title></head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li  style="list-style:none;">
        <input type = "radio" name = "trvltype" value = "oneway" id = "oneway" onclick = optionbuton()>One Way
        <input type = "radio" name = "trvltype" value = "return" id = "return" onclick = optionbuton()>Return
    </li>
</ul>

</body
</html>
```